# Print statement after the end=' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Using a range loop num set in python 3.7 and putting them all on the same line using the `end=''`
After that though I need on a separate line a print statement but the `end=''` stops it from appearing on a separate line when I run the module. Any way to work around that? Or even put the range loop on the same line without using the `end=''` expression?

Expected Output

```
3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30
That's all folks!
```

My code:

```
#uses loop from 3-30 counting by 3's

for num in range(3, 33, 3):

    print (num, end=' ')

#print statement

print("That's all folks!")
```

Comment: Show your code, don't describe it.

Comment: You can add an empty `print()` to get a newline

Answer (score 2):

First, make a list of numbers. Say it's called `number_list`.

Then use `",".join(number_list)` to join those numbers into a comma-delimited string.

Finally, print that string without `end=""`, and then print your second thing.

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around found out an easy way was just

print("\nprintstatement")

which thus created a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
for num in range(3, 33, 3):
    print(num, end=' ')

print("\nThat's all folks!")
```

Better:

```
print(*[*range(3, 33, 3)], "\nThat's all folks!")
```

> ```
> 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
> That's all folks!
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters @yawn it unpacks the list